# magento 2 Change the font and color of the product title?

Tags: magento-2.1, product

can anyone help me how to change the font and color of the product title? I don't have any theme? just installed the default Magento 2 product page

Comment: which theme you are using

Comment: @Gowthaman i am using default magento luma theme only i didn't install any theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under

`/public_html/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source`

you create a file called:`_extend.less`

add this code beneath it:

```
.base{
color: #ffffff ;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Adjust the color and font to the ones you want and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks @thomas meier i will check and get back to u thanks for your reply

Comment: hi thomas i tried but it's not effecting

Comment: i have deployed in pub folder also my changes are avilable

Comment: Can you post the filepath you used to implement the file? Also did you clear cache and deploy static content?